# Ajax requests without JQuery

Tags: ajax

I want to make Ajax requests without JQuery, and without including `wp_load.php`. I want to use a vanilla `XmlHttpRequest` object that I write myself.

Any links, hints, done-it-befores, etc?

Comment: Without including `wp-load.php` is absolutely fine but why you want to go without jQuery?

Comment: @Chittaranjan- it doesn't matter, but since you asked, I'm one of the crowd that doesn't use JQuery at the drop of a hat: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7152068, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099949/what-are-some-empirical-technical-reasons-not-to-use-jquery, http://www.sitepoint.com/do-you-really-need-jquery/, etc.

Comment: Do you mean without using WordPress to respond to request as well? Then what's WordPress left about the process at all? :)

Comment: @Rarst - because I need to access the wordpress posts :) I suppose I could PDO straight into `wp_posts` but it feels like there's a more wordpress-y way to do it...I'm trying to run a `getRecentPosts()` query so I'd like the native WP functionality to be intact.

Comment: if you use admin-ajax.php as ajax url,you will not need include wp-load.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming back to this on a new application. I just solved this using Angular, and a similar approach could be used with vanilla JS.

First, give Javascript access to the `admin-ajax.php` URL, something like:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var ajaxurl = '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."'</script>";
```

Next, in `functions.php`, register the action you want the Ajax to perform:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_infiniteScroll", "infiniteScroll");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_infiniteScroll", "infiniteScroll");
```

...and add an action handler which corresponds to the second parameter of the above actions:

```
function infiniteScroll() { 
    // This is what's returned to the client.
    echo "foo"; 
    die(); 
}
```

Now, all your ducks are in a row. Call `ajaxurl` with the `action` parameter set to the action you made above, and everything should work (below example with Angular):

```
$http({ url: ajaxurl + "?action=infiniteScroll" })
    .success(thenPopulate)
    .error(thenError);
```

---

Most solutions "require" JQuery (don't need it) and `wp_enqueue_scripts()` and a few other "convenience" functions (also not necessary).  The main thing is, make the URL available to your JS, register an action, and send that action in your request.

For those concerned about the globally visible `ajaxurl`, all of the other solutions I've read about use `wp_localize_script()` which makes a global variable anyway. With the above method, you can at least have a little control over its scope.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is grab data about a post/ posts, I'll seriously recommend using the JSON API plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).

I use it to make vanilla xmlhttp requests to a wp url and get back json